# Toolchain question: How do you add a header/lib so the compiler knows where to find it?

Tags: iphone, c, linux, compiler-construction, toolchain

I have made a toolchain using this script: http://gist.github.com/403608 (more or less modified to get it to work)

Everything is installed and now when I try to compile using it I get an error when I ./configure it says that my C compiler cannot create exeicutables.  I'm thinking that my compiler just doesn't know where to look for all the headers and libs... cause they are not in /usr/ they are in /var/sdk/usr/

is there a way to tell my compiler to always look in /var/sdk/usr/ also?

Comment: Which compiler are you wanting to tell this to?

Answer (score 1):

Most configure scripts use `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` environment variables to modify directory search paths for includes and libs.

```
LDFLAGS="-L/other/libs" CPPFLAGS="-I/other/includes" ./configure
```

You can also look at the compiler documentation as they usually have environment variables they look at as well.  For example gcc looks in directories listed `LIBRARY_PATH` for libs.  It will also look directories `CPATH` for includes.

Comment: can i just change the environment variable and then compile like normal and it will look there so long as those environment variables are set to that?

Comment: Those variables are only used and configure and compile time respectively.  You may need to update ldconfig and/or LD_LIBRARY_PATH for runtime modification of the directories examined for shared libs.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your target settings (control-click on a target and choose Info). Select the Build tab, then fill in Header Search Paths for headers, Library Search Paths for libraries.

Comment: Ah. Have you tried ./configure --help? configure normally has command-line options for specifying non-standard dependency locations.

Answer (score 0):

For gcc, use the [directory search options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)

```
    gcc -L/foo/bar/baz
    gcc -I/foo/bar/quux
```

The first one adds the directory /foo/bar/baz to the linker search path (libs will be found here).  The second one adds the directory /foo/bar/quux to the *front* on the list of directories to search for headers.  Mixed and multiple -I and -L options can occur in a single invocation.  If you use multiple "-I"s, they are searched in left to right order and then the system directories are searched.

Comment: is this only for that ONE compile or does it "stick" - as in configure GCC to always look there in the future?

Comment: @Jeremy Iglehart:  Just works the once.  But you're making a compile script or using make or some other method to automate this step so you only have to figure it out once.  I strongly recommend against changing your all-the-time environment since it makes a strong difference between development and production environments.